# Linking to a particular focus and zoom in Google My Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a [Google My Map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zB-9UUxMM5cM.kuVY3kBZBoY4&z=100) which lists places in the US. By default, the map zooms to the full US to include all places. I'd like to be able to link to specific focus/zoom levels (e.g. just places in NYC), but the URL doesn't change when I change focus in the UI. Is there any way to hack the URLs to do this?

Comment: @jbchurchill based on http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115165/65604 (which pertains to the API and is from 2013) I tried appending "&z=#" (e.g. &z=9) to the URL, but this didn't change anything. I couldn't find any guidance on the My Maps tool, or how much overlap there is with the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the zoom level of an embedded Google My Maps by adding "&z=X" where X is the zoom, so in your case you would embed your map like so:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=11taTOqfaQSmlryJCcCcwdanSiew&z=10" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Just change the z=X to whatever zoom you need. Hopefully this helps answer your question .

Comment: Thanks! Looks like they fixed this since 2016, it now works in My Maps as well.

Answer (score 2):

Now I see that you specified "My Maps" which means you won't be editing your answer to include any code (since you don't have that ability with "My Maps"). Everything I've found from Google indicates that you aren't going to be able to do this. [Evidence of inability to edit zoom level and center](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/d8SxD7Z0YJE)

**However**, I did find [this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/syq8Civg2rI) showing a method that would work for an embedded map (if your map is embedded in your website). This forum posting is similar to the link you posted in your comment. At first I thought that you wouldn't be able to enter that in the URL. I suspected that it would have to be embedded, but you commented that it works as a viewer (but not always in editor mode)! The code looks like this ...

```
<iframe src=".../embed?mid=...&z=12&ll=56.4567,-3.4567" ..
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually does work even when not embedded, as a viewer (not editor). For example, these two center on the Empire State Building with different zooms: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zB-9UUxMM5cM.kuVY3kBZBoY4&z=25&ll=40.748817%2C-73.985428
https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zB-9UUxMM5cM.kuVY3kBZBoY4&z=1&ll=40.748817%2C-73.985428

However, there seems to be a bug where the zoom doesn't work from the editor view, see http://imgur.com/a/Sbru6

In any case, if you'd like to edit I can mark as answered, or I can edit.